# GAE JAVA - Getting Object by Property

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have Entity say, `User { id (primary_key), phone }` to be stored in Datastore.

While Retrieving same i can use `getObjectById(User.class,id)` to get object. Is there way to get object with non-key property, say phone.

As per the documentation, Datastore creates index updates for Property "phone" too.
How do we use this index to get result?

Comment: thats what a Query is for.

Comment: @BillyFrost pardon me for this just want to confirm, Will query api use EntityPropertyIndex on non-key attribute?

Comment: No idea what "EntityPropertyIndex" is; nothing to do with JDO. A query will generate whatever statement that the datastore requires, and you can see what it is doing in the log

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a [JDO Query](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries) like following and Datastore will query on the non-key phone property (assuming you haven't set to to be [unindexed](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#Datastore_Unindexed_properties)).

q = pm.newQuery(User.class,"phone == '1234567890'");